# Define a function that returns all of the non-trivial splits of a list as a list of pairs

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming

I'm new to Haskell and have been given a worksheet question which has me stumped. The question is asking me to define a function that takes a list and returns a list of tuples, each of which contains a sub list of the original list.

[image]

I have tried the below. However, as expected, on each recursion the the previous head gets dropped.

```
splits :: [Int] -> [([Int],[Int])]
splits []
  = [([],[])]
splits (l:ls)
  = ([] ++ [l], ls) : splits ls
```

Here is the result I get.

```
[([1],[2,3,4]),([2],[3,4]),([3],[4]),([4],[]),([],[])]
```

Any advice on how to do this would be appreciated!

Comment: Why are the empty lists not part of the answer?

Comment: The title at least does stipulate *non-trivial* splits; it's not clear if that's stated in the original problem or added by the OP.

Comment: This is somewhat trivial if you are allowed to use `Data.List.inits` and `Data.List.tails`.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to prepend the first items in the result of the recursive call with `l`, so

```
splits :: [a] -> [([a], [a])]
splits [] = []
splits (l:ls) = ([l], ls) : map f (splits ls)
    where f (x, y) = (l:x, y)
```

or with `first`:

```
import Control.Arrow(first)

splits :: [a] -> [([a], [a])]
splits [] = []
splits (l:ls) = ([l], ls) : map (first (l:)) (splits ls)
```

Answer (score 0):

This also removes the item which has an empty tail :

```
splits :: [Int] -> [([Int], [Int])]
splits [] = []
splits [x] = []
splits (x : xs) = ([x], xs) : map f (splits xs)
  where
    f (z, y) = (x : z, y)
```